# Demistifying Multinomial Naive Bayes with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, naivebayes

I'd like to ask a few questions about a code snippet to see if the plethora of experts that wander on stackoverflow can demistify a couple of cryptic lines in a piece of code that I used a while ago and that now I'm reimplementing. It's supposed to be a Bayesian classifier based on a multinomial distribution (although I plan to use it with TF-IDF weights).

This is the code I literally just copied from a thread I opened a while back:

```py
import numpy as np


class MultinomialNB(object):
    """A Naive Bayes for Multinomial classification using
       discrete features such as word frequencies or tf-idf
       weights for text classification.

       :smoothing: Laplacian additive smoothing parameter (default 1.0)
       :type smoothing: float, optional
    """

    def __init__(self, *, smoothing: float = 1.0):
        """Object constructor"""

        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.priors = None
        self.features_proba = None
        self.is_fit = False

    def fit(self, X: np.array, y: np.array):
        """
        Fits the classifier according to X, y

        :param X: A n*m matrix where n is the number of samples and m
        the number of features in the dataset
        :type X: np.array
        :param y: The associated values to the X
        :type y: np.array
        :returns: self
        :rtype: class: TSDE.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB
        """
        split_classes = [[x for x, cat in zip(X, y) if cat == cls] for cls in np.unique(y)]
        self.priors = [np.log(len(x) / X.shape[0]) for x in split_classes]
        # What's happening below here? 
        frequencies = np.array([np.array(cls).sum(axis=0) for cls in split_classes]) + self.smoothing
        self.features_proba = np.log(frequencies / frequencies.sum(axis=1)[np.newaxis].T)
        self.is_fit = True
        return self

    def predict(self, X: np.array) -> np.array:
        """Performs classification on the array of test vectors X

           :param X: The array of test vectors to perform
           classification on
           :type X: np.array
           :returns: The prediction result
           :rtype: np.array
        """

        assert self.is_fit, "The model must be fit before predicting!"
        # ??? 
        return np.argmax([(self.features_proba * x).sum(axis=1) + self.priors for x in X], axis=1)
```

I'll summarize which lines are unclear to me, specifically. First, the `fit` method: From my understanding, this does the following:

- Split the X matrix into classes
- Calculate the prior log probabilities for each class
- ???

I'm not quite understanding what happens next, which I guess means I'm wondering what `self.features_proba` or `frequencies` are supposed to mean. What would those be in the Bayesian equation? Aren't just the priors enough when training?

Next, my other doubt comes from `predict`. Since I know how naive Bayes works and read the documentation on `numpy.argmax`, I figured out that it's job is to pick the highest log probability among the predicted ones for each class, but I'm not really understanding what that bit of code does or why it does that.

Comment: Could you summarize the exact lines and keywords that you do not understand? You could rewrite summing over an axis or broadcasting by using simple for-loops if you want a better understanding of how numpy might work under the hood.

Comment: I have worked a bit with naive bayes, but I am not confident enough to explain why the code is doing what it is doing :)

Comment: @Kevin I edited the question with the information you've asked me, hopefully you can help me figure this out!

Comment: This is a very long question. I might pare it down to just the fundamental question. :-)

Comment: @erip I know it's very long, but I didn't want to omit potentially useful information and this problem is kings complex for me :)

Comment: @erip got any updates for me? I'm really struggling and I would love to complete this project since I'm planning to do language and topic detection and then spam detection too with this model

Comment: My update is that you should post a more minimal question. No one is going to want to read a wall of text. Especially since this doesn't seem to contain a question

Comment: @erip: It does contain the question. There's even questions marks if it wasn't clear enough: "I'm not quite understanding what happens next, which I guess means I'm wondering what self.features_proba or frequencies are supposed to mean. What would those be in the Bayesian equation?"

Comment: I've reduced the question size significantly, btw.